# Curve edges of cylinder extrusion inward like an arc

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I have a cylinder which I've extruded like so:
[image: Cylinder]

I want to convert those edges to be curved like an arc inwards like so:

[image: arc]

Such that the entire bottom section is curved (the faces along with the edges).

Note: beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the bottom shape like this

[image]

Select this edge loop

[image]

Hit <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> to create a bevel and play with the Shape slider

[image]

You can turn on Clamp Overlap and adjust the Width to get it to go all the way to the outer edges

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Thank you so so much for the effort in this answer! Is it possible to get the top line of the curve to merge with the cylinder? I guess by making the segments thin enough I could approximate that. 

I will experiment with this and maybe I'll stumble on something!

Comment: @Hmm See the last comment in my answer, "turn on Clamp Overlap and adjust the Width" This tells Blender to stop allowing any more adjustment when an outside edge touches another edge. So you can drag the Width slider until the bevel stops getting any bigger. It does create overlapping vertices but selecting all then merge by distance will clean that up :)

Comment: HISEROD answer below is actually an easier way to do that :)

Comment: AH! Sorry about that, didn't understand the first time. Makes sense! Thank you. I will try both methods. Man... I love the internet. So many kind people!

Answer (score 3):

Just make your extrusion (<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in my case) and bevel the inner edge loop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: How do you make the extrusion only along the X and Y axis?

Comment: Never mind, found the answer, for those looking press E to extrude, then S to scale!